# Change form field style in Drupal 7

Tags: module, drupal-7

I am currently creating a drupal 7 module.

I have a textfield :

```
$form['gestionvideos_videos']['input'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="customSearch">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#attributes' => array('onkeyup' => 'search();'),
      );
```

And I want to put an image in front of it, and align both of them on the right of my container. I have no clue how I could do it ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$form['gestionvideos_videos']['input'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<img src="/image.jpg" align="left" width="20px" height="20px"/><div id="customSearch">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#attributes' => array('onkeyup' => 'search();'),
  );
```